# Domino limitation whith CXF web service?

Tags: web-services, web, cxf, lotus-domino

An xpages application I'm developing consumes a web service that stores files that are attached to an xpages in a repository. To do this I call an agent developed in Java, whose client to consume the web service was created from the framework APACHE CXF.
Files up to 2.5 MB are stored without problems in the repository, however larger files the web service gives the error below. I did the same procedure consuming the web service through Eclipse and the error did not happen for files larger than 2.5 MB. Does anyone know if the problem is related to some Domino server configuration? Can it be a communication problem between the Domino server and the server where the repository resides? Has anyone had an analogous problem?

Java.io.IOException: Error writing to server

```
HTTP JVM: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Error 
writing to server
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:213)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:163)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:95)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:117)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:599)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:558)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:543)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:440)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:223)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:136)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:110)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:90)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:119)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.incluirDossie(Unknown Source)
HTTP JVM:   at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
HTTP JVM:   at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
HTTP JVM:   at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
HTTP JVM: Caused by: 
HTTP JVM: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
HTTP JVM:   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:594)
HTTP JVM:   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:606)
HTTP JVM:   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1228)
HTTP JVM:   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
HTTP JVM:   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:210)
HTTP JVM:   ... 16 more
```

Comment: I've developed some web service clients using jax-ws on domino within java agents. I've never had problems like this and transfered larger files than 2.5MB. According to my experience, I can't imagine that a config on the domino server can cause that issue. Can you provide a complete stack trace an not just the final message?

Comment: I put the stack trace in the question

Comment: The stack trace looks like you don't use apache cxf at runtime. It more looks like that you use the jvm integrated jax-ws client. Do you have the apache cxf libraries attached to the agent or placed them into jvm/lib/ext? If you attach the libraries to the agent, you should be aware that a memory leak exists with attached libraries (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO49880). The best way is to add them via notes.ini var JavaUserClasses or JavaUserClassesExt.

Comment: I do not have the apache cfx libraries, nor attached to the agent, nor in the jvm / lib / ext directory. What would these libraries be? Could you list them?

Comment: As I said, I didn't implement my web services with Apache CXF and therefore I don't know which libraries you need for the Apache CXF runtime. I've used JAXB and the maven jaxws-maven-plugin to generate web service clients and they run well on Domino within agents.
But I'm not able to provide a solution for your generated code with Apache CXF. Maybe you don't need any libraries if you use the bundled jax-ws from Java 6. But then, you should keep in mind, that the version of jax-ws is 2.0 and not 2.2 and your tests within eclipse run also with a java 6 SE JRE. I hope you find a solution!

Comment: Do you have any procedure how to generate the client web service with JAXB?

Comment: Are you familiar with maven? I use the jaxws-maven-plugin to generate the web service client and the jaxws-rt 2.2.1 dependency to run it. It would be much more to describe the hole procedure, configuration as this comment would allow and my time is a little bit rare this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Domino server's "Maximum size of request content" and "Maximum POST Data" settings?  The default is usually 10MB and unlimited(0), respectively, but may have been set to something lower.  The settings are found in the server document, then go to the Internet Protocols - Domino Web Engine tab.  Check what the values are and update as needed.  A restart of HTTP is required if you change the setting.

Comment: that can not be a solution for this issue since this settings are only relevant for web service providers but not clients